# How to add Buttons above notification list

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I want to add Buttons Above notification list in Notification bar,
as we see on galaxy tab buttons (Wi-fi, Bluetooth, GPS, Silent buttons)
I want to add buttons below these button not in notification list.

Is it possible?
How to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a custom rom such as CyanogenMod or MIUI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can explain more on this. what is rom?

Comment: Right now you are probably running AOSP(Android Open Source Project) on your phone. It is the default rom for androids. Custom roms like CyanogenMod add extra features to the phone that previously were not available. Although they add more features, they can have bugs and also void your warranty. You should first google for "android root" and "android roms" to find out what it's all about. Here is a bit more info http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/05/01/custom-roms-for-android-explained-and-why-you-want-them/

Comment: Got it, Is it must to get custom rom to add buttons above Notification list, I am writing an generic application which can be used on any rom. so is there any way.

Comment: I dont think an app can do anything to the notification bar. I always thought of it as the only thing thats visible but isn't an app on android :D BTW, the Galaxy S only has that because it is also running a different rom...